# How to troubleshoot/debug a MySQL slow query?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, debugging

If you have a slow SQL query, how do you debug it?

Where do you start and what are the steps needed to identify the problem?

I'm new to this subject and searching online wouldn't give me a clear idea how to start.

Comment: I think this question should be answered. There are many questions here on stackoverflow that  more broad than this and most of them have answers. I think it's reasonable to ask about a checklist for the things you can do when you debug a slow query.

Comment: I agree with @Yuck. This question is far too broad and should be closed immediately by a moderator. And hfatahi, if you find other questions that are too broad, those should be closed too, regardless of how many answers they have. Just because a question has an answer, doesn't mean it's on-topic for SO. I suggest reading the [help documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the part about what is considered [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best tool is to look at the execution plan.  On a high level, the execution plan shows how the query is executing, and what parts of the query take more processing relative to the other parts.  This is the best anyone on this site would be able to do for you without seeing the query, and the execution plan for that matter.  There are so many things that could be causing the problem.

Here are a few references (depending on what version of MySQL you are in)-
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/execution-plan-information.html